# c# http request method name "POST /sample.xml"

Tags: c#, xml

Post sample xml method exception message : 403

http request name edit but not working

```
        HttpWebRequest request;
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse;


        WebResponse rsp = null;


        Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.75:80");


        string postData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>"...";

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUri.AbsoluteUri);
        //WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
        //myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Content-Type:text/xml charset=utf8");
        //myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Content-Length:124");



        request.Method = "POST /sample.xml";

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] body = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "text/xml charset=utf8";
        request.Accept = "text/html";
      //  request.Accept = "/setup.xml";

        request.ContentLength = body.Length;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(body, 0, body.Length);
        newStream.Close();


       myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

right POST:

POST /sample.xml HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 124

....

please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 request.Method = "POST /sample.xml";
```

should be

```
request.Method = "POST";
```

And

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.75:80");
```

Should be

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.75:80/sample.xml");
```

In addition, the handler /sample.xml must exists on yout server and a=must accept POST requests.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex  ^^,